# Using react ui project using local path on package.json - got an error Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, package.json

I have a custom ui project A (built in react / material-ui / typescript)
and react project B which uses the component from project A.

I've installed the A into B using file path on package.json, but getting a following error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

I've looked into the solutions from other posts tried this one - 
since both A,B projects have react, I've included react on A as a **peer dependency.**

But, still when I try `npm ls react`, it has two react saying that

> react@16.11.0  extraneous

How can I fix this npm error extraneous?

UPDATE:
so, when i publish this project A and install it on B, it works fine.
But when i intall A using file path on package.json, it has the error like above.